# Flask required form on home page

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, flask-login

I am looking for some kind of example with flask using a required form on the home page of my site that requires the user to select an option before being allowed onto the rest of the site. The form is used for selecting a collection out of my mongo db database. I need to know what collection the user wants to use before going anywhere else on the site. Once this done I need to make sure I can use this information on my other route and views on my site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is to implement a login infrastructure.

using flask, you have a base template, where every other template is `extending`, what you can do is something like the following:

`base.html`:

```
{% if current_user.is_authenticated %}
    <content>
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
    </content>  
{% else %}
    <login-form>
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
    </login-form>
{% endif %}
```

using this code, the content is shown only and only if the user is authenticated.  in `login-form` HTML you should have a `form` to ask the credentials needed to authenticate the user and then allow them access to rest of the site.

in other template files, you continue to use the same practice:

`dashboard.html`:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
  <YOUR HTML CONTENT>
{% endblock %}
```

the content of `dashboard.html` is only shown to the user, if they are logged in(`current_user.is_authenticated = True`)

this is because `dashboard.html` is shown inside the `content` block of `base.html` witch is only shown or rendered if that condition is met.

you can use anything else instead of `is_authenticated` like the collection being selected or anything like that. the procedure to do it is the same.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. And thank you that worked for me.